# Combine the keys of dictionary if they have similar value: Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Let us say I have the following two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {10: 0.28, 20: 0.12, 30: 0.16, 40: 0.15, 50: 0.08, 110:0.28}
dict2 = {60: 0.12, 70: 0.28, 80: 0.17, 90: 0.19, 100: 0.08}
```

I would like to compare their values. If they have similar values, I would like to combine their keys. For example, 10 and 70 have value 0.28 and I would like to combine them as `10/70`. As such, for 20 and 60 as `20/60`. Similarily for 50 and 100 as `50/100`.

And for the rest, for example, 0.16 is existed only in dict1 only so I would like to put it as `30/-`. Similarly for 80 in dict2 has no match in dict1 so I would like to put it as `-/80`.

In addition, for 110 from the first dictionary, it has value of 0.28 which is similar with key 10 in the first dictionary and key 70 in the second dictionary. So, in this case, I don want to put twice means there is `10/70` but not `110/70`. 70 become duplicate. I would like to see `110/-`

Generally, I would like to see the following result.

```
updated_dict = {10:10/70, 20:20/60, 30:30/-, 40:40/-, 50:50/100, 60:20/60, 70:10/70, 80:-/80, 90:-/90, 100:50/100, 110:110/-}
```

This is how I tried:

```
for key, val in dict2.items():
    if (dict1.get(key, None) == val):
        print(str(key) + '/' + str(key))
```

But couldn't get what I want.

Is there any way to achieve this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Initialising all the variables.

```
dict1 = {10: 0.28, 20: 0.12, 30: 0.16, 40: 0.15, 50: 0.08}
dict2 = {60: 0.12, 70: 0.28, 80: 0.17, 90: 0.19, 100: 0.08}
dict3 = dict()
```

Next we have to create a function to reverse the key value pair of a dictionary so that we can get the key of a value.

```
def reverse(dictionary):
    dict_reverse = dict()
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        dict_reverse[value] = key
    return dict_reverse
```

Next, we check if the value is present in both the dictionaries. Then we add the keys to dict3.

```
for key, val in dict2.items():
    if val in dict1.values():
        key2 = reverse(dict1)[val]
        dict3[key2] = str(key2) + "/" + str(key)
        dict3[key] = str(key2) + "/" + str(key)
        dict1[key2] = “”
        dict2[key] = “”
    else:
        dict3[key] = "-/" + str(key)
```

Then we check if there is any value in dict1 which is not there in dict2. The keys of such values are then added to dict3

```
for key, val in dict1.items():
        if val not in dict2.values():
            dict3[key] = str(key) + "/-"
```

Result-

```
dict3 = {20: '20/60', 60: '20/60', 110: '110/70', 70: '110/70', 80: '-/80', 90: '-/90', 50: '50/100', 100: '50/100', 10: '10/-', 30: '30/-', 40: '40/-'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  for large dictionaries, is it possible also to have a condition for a key to match for only once? For example, ```10/10, 10/20```.  Here ```10``` appeared twice. So, instead, ```10/10``` then for the second 10  ```-/20```.